# What is the best way to handle large data set for excel?

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

I have large data set, in different table form and i am using this data on excel for some analysis. Currently i am using excel but file is going large day by day and slowing to process.  Can any busy tell me what is best way to store (database) data for excel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get to a point where excel is getting to slow to efficiently work with. I don't think you need all historic data while working in excel. I would select data from your database and create a summarized or filtered csv or excel file on which you can work with - if you want to work with excel.
I had the same problem once. Your excel file will maybe work for months but it is getting slower and slower until you cannot use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the best way to export Access data to Excel, then open Excel file using Excel library and use CopyFromRecordset. See, for instance, example [here](https://desmondoshiwambo.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/export-a-recordset-from-access-into-excel-using-the-excel-method-copyfromrecordset/)

Comment: No sir, i want to know where i store the data? I mean when data required we call it in excel,  by doing all this process  i want to speed up my excel file.